# Value of variable changing after function ends

Tags: c, matrix

I'm doing an exercise for school that uses a matrix and functions to fill it with random numbers between 0 and 20 and display the values on screen, but after the first function ends the value in the variables that store the size of the matrix change, and it's related to the random numbers since it's always a number between 0 and 20, even if they aren't passed by reference, this happens only if the size of the matrix is bigger than 3x4 or 4x3, e.g 4x4 or more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void creaMatrix(int base, int height, int matrix[base][height]){
  for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

      matrix[i][j] = rand()%21;

    }
  }
}

void visualizzaMatrix(int base, int height, int matrix[base][height]){
  for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

      printf("%d\t",matrix[i][j]);

    }

    printf("\n");

  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int n = 0 , m = 0;
  int matrix[n][m];

  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

  printf("base:\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("height:\n");
  scanf("%d",&m);

  creaMatrix(n,m,matrix);
  printf("n: %d m: %d\n",n, m); // here n and m change value for some reason
  visualizzaMatrix(n,m,matrix);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `n` and `m` when the `int matrix[n][m];` declaration is made? (Clue: greater than -1 but less than +1.)

Comment: That solved it, thanks!

Comment: Once you have a zero-sized array and write-access any of its elements, you have undefined behaviour (who knows *where* you are writing to). From that point on, all bets are off. Move the array declaration to ***after*** you know the values of `m` and `n`. Looking for a suitable duplicate ...